# Checking bandwith without using fast.com

Tags: linux, networking

How does one check the bandwidth on Linux devices without a GUI? Normally this could be done with a browser and [online speed tests](https://fast.com) but this isn't possible on a command line only device, apart from checking the latency using `ping`.

Comment: https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski would have marked this as correct if it was an answer

Comment: Make it an answer if you wish. I deliberately didn't because I have very limited experience with this tool.

Answer (score 2):

Look for hosters that offer test download binaries. These were originally meant for potential customers to guage the speed of their network, but they can also be used for speed testing a client.

You can use the following command to do a speed test:

```
wget --report-speed=bits -O /dev/null $url
```

Some suggestions:

- https://binfiles.net/
- https://testfiledownload.com/
- https://speed.hetzner.de/

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into [`iperf`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/iperf.1.html). The application consists of a server and a client, [this page for example](https://www.techtarget.com/searchnetworking/tip/How-to-use-iPerf-to-measure-throughput) explains what steps you need to follow.

If you want to check your local network throughput you could host a local `iperf` server. If you're interested in speed over the internet you could connect to one of the [public `iperf` servers](https://iperf.fr/iperf-servers.php).